# Python editor with automatic code completion?

Tags: python, ide, editor, intellisense, code-completion

I have seen various articles about good Python editors/IDEs, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python). However, none of them points out whether the editors support ***automatic*** code completion. I tried notepad++, PyScript and Komodo Edit, but all of these requires a hotkey to invoke the code completion dialog.

Do you know any Python editors with automatic code completion?

Answer (score 4):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905005/python-and-intellisense) shows how to do it with vim/gvim, eclipse/pydev, IDLE, wingware -- however no answer is clear about the "automatic" part (which would of course still require confirmation, since there's never an absolute certainty!-).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse with pydev extension should work.

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana pydev](http://www.pydev.org/) (based on eclipse)?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux)

They have explained how to install and how to use.
I am using Pycharm from last year It's quit helpful in tab completion and other things like setting project configuration for virtual env, git anaconda etc...