# ide code information

Tags: c++, python, c, ide, code-completion

I've been annoyed lately by the fact that PyDev doesn't information about classes and function when it code completes wxPython code.

Can anybody tell me FOSS IDE's or extensions that offer code information (function params, returns etc.) when it code completes for C/C++ and Python.

I am a fan of CodeLite, Eclipse CDT and CodeBlocks in that order for C/C++ (excepting non-FOSS)
and PyScripter, PyDev for Python in that order.

Comment: Have you seen this message that relates to your problem? http://old.nabble.com/-pydev---Users--Autocompletion-with-wxPython-in-Eclipse-td21585224.html

Comment: I haven't tried to re-add the interpreter into PyDev, but still I want to know if there are better alternatives, or IDE's that have better support for this feature

Comment: While it's not OSS, Wing IDE does have a free personal/student edition. I don't know how robust it is with wxPython, but the few days I played around with it it was pretty impressive. See: http://www.wingware.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) + [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)

See [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/lharris/2008/07/20/code-completion-with-vim-7/), [here](http://insenvim.sourceforge.net/) and [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=747) for **C++** autocompletion (also referred to as IntelliSense, taken from the name for Visual Studio's autocomplete).

And [here](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/) for **Python** autocomplete/"intellisense" for vim. (I should point out I found the link to that from [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905005/python-and-intellisense/905036#905036)).

If that doesn't include the ctags for **wxPython** as you require, you might want to check out [this guy's ctags-based highlighting](http://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/ctags-highlighting) which apparently does work for wxPython (and perhaps take the ctags file from that?)

Probably also worth checking out [this enormous list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) of Python IDEs on SO (specifically those with "AC" tags) if you've not already seen that? I realise your question is a bit more specific than just basic Auto Complete, but perhaps there's some new options in there for you...

Comment: you wouldn't happen to have a pre built version, wouldn't you ?

great answer by the way, I asked another question in another thread and your answer answers both

thx

Answer (score 0):

I use notepad++ and am vary happy with it.