# Which editors for Scala support automatic code completion?

Tags: scala, editor

Which editors for Scala support automatic code completion? (A.k.a. "intellisense".)

([This popular unclosed q.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905005/python-and-intellisense) asks which Python editors support automatic code completion, so I hope this is not off topic.)

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ is one of the editors out there and the community version which is free has enough features to use.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows

IntelliJ is developed by JetBrains and they offer many good products, not all of them either are free or have a community variant, I especially like their Resharper addin for Visual Studio, fyi.