# How to make IntelliSense in Python behave as it does in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, intellisense

When I write C# code in VS Code and start typing some word and IntelliSense appears and focus on some suggestion I can press dot or space and this word appears in code.
But in python I strictly have to press Enter only if I want to get suggested word. Is it possible to make IntelliSense in Python behave like it behaves in C#?

Comment: This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/905005/20654632

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following lines to your settings.json file

```js
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": true,
  "strings": true
}
```

Comment: this doesn't help(

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @DreamyPlayer's answer, add the following line to `settings.json` (or rewrite it, if key `editor.inlineSuggest.enabled` exists):

```json
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true
```